# Separation of business logic "tasks" that aren't surfaced in the UI

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture

`DataSourceA` provides data in the format below;

```kotlin
data class Foo(
    val someId: String,
    val someData: List<String>,
    val someMoreData: List<String>
)
```

I take this data into my domain layer and perform logic/validation on it, producing below and saving it to my local Room database.

```kotlin
data class ValidatedFoo(
    val someId: String,
    val isSupported: Boolean,
    val isSomeCheck: Boolean,
) {
    companion object {
        internal fun validateFoo(foo: Foo) =
            ValidatedFoo(
                someId = foo.someId,
                isSupported = isSupported(foo.someData),
                isSomeCheck = isSomeCheck(foo.someMoreData)
            )

        private fun isSupported(someData: List<String>): Boolean {
            return setOf("A","B","C").any { it in someData }
        }

        private fun isSomeCheck(someMoreData: List<String>): Boolean {
            return setOf("X","Y","Z").all { it in someMoreData }
        }
    }
}
```

Within my local database I also have the below model that comes from `DataSourceB`;

```kotlin
data class Bar(
    val someId: String,
    val someDataForUi: String,
    val someMoreDataForUi: Int
)
```

I present this to the UI layer via `Domain.UseCase` < `Data.BarRepository` < `Local.BarDao`

Where `Local.BarDao` contains;

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT b.* FROM Bar b INNER JOIN ValidatedFoo f ON f.someId=b.someId WHERE f.isSupported=true")
fun getSupportedBars(): List<Bar>
```

`Foo` nor `ValidatedFoo` are ever required outside of the Domain layer, `Foo` updates are retrieved from a separate data source on completely different events/triggers to those of `Bar`. `Bar` is updated/requested via the UI. `Foo` is updated based on a network query containing a value (eg `network.lastUpdated > local.lastUpdated`).

On this basis, I don't know where I should perform the requests for `Foo` updates, should I monitor the state of the `Foo` update value in the domain layer and push `ValidatedFoo` straight back to the data layer without ever surfacing it in the UI layer? That doesn't *feel* correct, but neither does surfacing it in the UI layer when the UI doesn't ever need to concern itself with `Foo`. I've massively over-simplified the validation taking place on `Foo` in the above example.

Comment: Why do you want to monitor the state of Foo? It's observable? Basically, from all places that trigger should trigger Foo download, call a Update Validated Foo use case, for example. UI should not be aware of it.